# How do I reliably find the full path of a program on the PATH?

Tags: shell, path

I need to find the path of a given program on the `PATH` using a shell script. The path must be the actual full path of the program, which can be passed later to one of the `exec*` functions, which does not search the `PATH` itself, e.g. `execv`.

There are programs like `kill`, which are available as an actual program and a shell built-in at the same time. If this is case, I need the full path to the actual program.

There are several utilities that can find a program on the `PATH` as specified in [Section 2.9.1.1, Command Search and Execution of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01).

There is `which`, which is not part of any standard. It can be a regular program on some systems, whereas some shells provide it is a builtin. It seems to be available on most systems and shells, but the shells with a builtin version, also just return the name of the built-in instead of the path to the executable. Also it is not standardized in any way and may return any output and take different options.

```
bash# which kill
/usr/bin/kill
dash# which kill
/usr/bin/kill
fish# which kill
/usr/bin/kill
mksh# which kill
/usr/bin/kill
tcsh# which kill
kill: shell built-in command.
zsh# which kill
kill: shell built-in command
```

There is `whence`, which is a built-in of a few shells. But not available on many shells. It will too return the name of the built-in instead of the path to program. A `-p` may be passed to whence to change this behavior.

```
bash# whence kill
bash: whence: command not found
dash# whence kill
dash: 1: whence: not found
fish# whence kill
fish: Unknown command 'whence'
mksh# whence kill
kill
mksh# whence -p kill
/usr/bin/kill
tcsh# whence kill
whence: Command not found.
zsh# whence kill
kill
zsh# whence -p kill
/usr/bin/kill
```

There is the [`command` builtin specified by POSIX:2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html). Unfortunately it also searches for regular commands and built-ins and will return the name of the built-in instead of the path to the program shadowed by a built-in of the same name. Some old shells haven't implemented it yet.

```
bash# command -v kill
kill
dash# command -v kill
kill
fish# command -v kill
/usr/bin/kill
mksh# command -v kill
kill
tcsh# command -v kill
command: Command not found.
zsh# command -v kill
kill
```

Comment: I can't figure out if `enable` is specified in POSIX or not, but if it is, you could use `enable -n which` to disable the shell built-in for `which`.

Comment: and there is `realpath`

Comment: @Muzer On the shells I have at my disposal, `enable` is only provided by `bash` and `zsh`

Comment: @IporSircer AFAIK `realpath` canonicalizes path names, i.e. expands symbolic links and resolves `.` and `..`. This has nothing to do with command searching.

Comment: You need a realiable method for _the specific shell which is running your script_ not for all shells. Scripts are not executed by a random shell but specifically by the shell specified in the shebang line. That being said, in bash that would be `type -p`. Both bash and dash let you say `command` command to run an actual executable even if there is a function or builtin with the same name.

Comment: @AlexP `command` skips functions (and aliases) but NOT builtins, as the Q correctly says. And you can't always use a shebang because there is no path that gets any given shell, or even some POSIX shell, on all systems.

Comment: Some systems (e.g. Debian) could have [realpath(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) to be used, for example, as `$(realpath $0)`

Comment: Doesn't explicitly answer the question, but an example workaround is to prepend the command with a backslash; e.g. `\kill`

Comment: A backslash before a command will just prevent shells from using alias expansion, it has no effect on shell built-ins such as `command`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just search for it yourself.

```
export IFS=":"
[ -z "${1}" ] && exit 1
for dir in $PATH
do if [ -x "${dir}/${1}" ]
   then echo "${dir}/${1}"
        exit 0
   fi
done
echo ${1} not found
exit 1
```

Tested in `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, `zsh`

## Update

The above is nice for a stand alone script however if you're planning on embedding this into a larger script you may want to use something more like the following.

```
function find_path() {
   IFS_SAVE="${IFS}"
   export IFS=":"
   [ -z "${1}" ] && return 1
   for dir in $PATH
   do if [ -x "${dir}/${1}" ]
      then echo "${dir}/${1}"
           export IFS="${IFS_SAVE}"
           return 0
      fi
   done
   export IFS="${IFS_SAVE}"
   echo ${1} not found
   return 1
}
```

This is so that `IFS` is restored after finding the match, also swapped `exit`'s with `return`'s

Comment: Maybe -x instead of -f?

Comment: @JeffSchaller good point, no reason to pick out non-executable files.

Comment: If you integrate this into a larger shell script (as opposed to making it into a script in its own right, as is presumably intended), you might want to restore the old value of IFS afterwards - otherwise that could have a lot of effects on the rest of the script...

Comment: Why export the `IFS` variable? Isn't it enough to have this set in the local shell? Speaking of local, would `local IFS` be portable? The above may interact poorly if something else is saving IFS the same way. Looking at [this question on SE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18597697/1468366), `local` may work for most shells despite not being POSIX. Putting the original version in a `(…)` subshell might work as well.